# How do I find the dot product of $\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{u}-\overrightarrow{v}$ with the given information?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I already know that $|\overrightarrow{u}|=2, |\overrightarrow{v}| = 3,|$ and $\langle\overrightarrow{u},\overrightarrow{v}\rangle = 1$. I am unsure as to how to proceed in order to find $\langle\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{u}-\overrightarrow{v}\rangle$. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Use bilinearity, and that $\left<u,u\right>=2^2$ and $\left<v,v\right>=3^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by bi-linearity? @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that
$$(u+v) \cdot (u-v)=u \cdot (u-v)+v \cdot (u-v)= u \cdot u -u \cdot v + v \cdot u - v \cdot v =...$$
Can you finish it?

Comment: I understand, thank you. I have one additional question. What is the purpose of including the: $-u\cdot v+v\cdot u$? Isn't $u\cdot v=v\cdot u$? So this would just be $-u\cdot v+v\cdot u=0$, right?

Comment: @MohammedShahid yes, they will cancel out each other.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $(u+v,u-v) = (u,u) - (u,v) + (v,u) - (v,v)$. You know all of the terms of the RHS of the previous equation.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$(\vec{u}+\vec{v})\cdot (\vec{u}-\vec{v})=\vec{u}^2-\vec{v}^2=|\vec{u}|^2-|\vec{u}|^2=…$$

Comment: How do you get $\vec{u}^2-\vec{v}^2=|\vec{u}|^2-|\vec{u}|^2$?

Comment: $$\vec{x}^2=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{x}=|\vec{x}|^2$$ after the laws of the dot-product.

Comment: Also using (a+b)(a-b)=$a^2-b^2$. This hold because of distributivity of vectors

Comment: So wouldn't it be $|\vec{u}|^2-|\vec{v}|^2$?

Comment: I have wrote you the reasons that it is right what i have written.

Comment: Better you review: at the end you wrote $|\vec{u}|^2-|\vec{u}|^2$ which is always $ 0$

Comment: It is always $0$ if $$|\vec{u}|=|\vec{v}|$$